# WordPress option page inner table elements not showing

Tags: html, wordpress

WordPress version: 4.8.1

I am creating my own plugin, but i got stuck on the option page. Created a function which called when you go to the page and inside this function elements like below are showing up.

```
<div class="wrap"></div>
<p></p>
<form class="form-table" method="post" action="options.php">
```

But elements inside the form element dont

```
<form>
<thead><th></th></thead>
<tbody><td></td></tbody>
</form>
```

Even when i use

```
echo '<form>
<thead><th></th></thead>
<tbody><td></td></tbody>
</form>';
```

Any suggestions? I want this way not using div's so my form has the same style as the rest of wordpress forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `<table></table>` tag itself...

Comment: Edited to include the full tag just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<table>` tag after `<form>` like this:

```
echo '<form>
<table>
<thead><th></th></thead>
<tbody><td></td></tbody>
</table>
</form>';
```